# How do you extend the menu css class for multi colors?

Tags: menu, css, color-picker

I have activated the extended menu via the Screen Options and in my menu item I have specified a class based on the css code added to the screeen.css file.

For example in the "Home" menu item I have specified a class of "red", and in the css I have added the following code.

```
   .red { color: #FF0000}
```

Unfortunately this is not transposing to the template and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Checking this with firebug I notice the class is being added, however the color change is not appearing.

```
     <li id="menu-item-154" class="red menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
       object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-148 current_page_item menu-
       item-154"> <a href="http://domain.com/WP-folder/?page_id=148">Home</a>
```

Can anyone offer some suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The color might be specified in one of the other classes as well.
You can try to remove that or you can try to force the color via the CSS `important` attribute.

Try:

```
.red { color: #FF0000 !important;}
```